# How can I open new pages from a page saved as an application in iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari

I'm working on an HTML5 application that should be able to run in a lot of different environments - most desktop web browsers, mobile web browsers, and as an application saved to an iOS device.

The problem is that it opens multiple separate pages using target="_blank", mostly for exporting or printing data, which in an iOS web application blows away the current window and leaves the user unable to return. A simple link back isn't a solution, as the main page has more state in it than can be reasonably passed around. Is there a way for iOS mobile applications to open their pages as new tabs in mobile Safari?

Answer (score 1):

If you are speaking about adding your web application to home screen and run it in standalone mode using:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Then the answer is No, sadly. I just finished project that needed to work like that and the only way you can open links in new "tab" is to create your own tabs with HTML/CSS/JS and open those links inside iframes.

Also you need to be aware of **X-Frame-Options: Deny** that blocks websites to load inside iframe.
For example google, facebook... can't be opened inside an iframe anymore since they want to [protect them self against **Clickjacking**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_replace).

At the end I end up making my app 100% javascript based and done everything on index.html page.
I also done some AJAX requests when I needed something from the server side...
And It works perfectly.

If you are using JQuery, see: [handling downloads of exported material via ajax](http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx).